# My keyboard types multiple letters if I type too quickly

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Sometimes when I type the keyboard types anywhere between 2 and 10 extra characters.  So for example:

> This wooorddd is creaaaaaaaazy

It can make typing an email a nightmare.  And sometimes when deleting it might do 8 deletes, so equally as annoying and that's not typing quickly.

I've trying changing the repeat  rate in my settings.  It's almost as if something is taking over my computer and swallowing all the memory as it buffers and then suddenly does like 8 letters.

If it was just buffering I'd assume memory (unlikely for a keyboard).    But as it's duplication I think it must be something else.  I've put new batteries in the keyboard and it doesn't seem to happen all the time but it does sometimes.

I've also tried downloading software here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/which-devices-are-supported-by-microsoft-mouse-and-keyboard-center-61ac6d03-9cc1-d7c6-ca9b-c9c8ce4cb303 but it doesn't find my bluetooth keyboard.  They list it as "ergonmic keyboard" although if you buy it it's called "Microsoft Surface Ergnomic Keyboard".  Kind of annoying that they also named their new laptops surface too.  Makes finding support much harder.

Can anyone think of why this might be because it's becoming really annoying.

**Update: this did not solve the issue.**

I believe this may have been caused by a Bluetooth clash.  My motherboard has built-in Bluetooth and I think one of the drivers is wonky for some reason.  It's always showed up as a warning sign on device manager but the update button doesn't find an update.

I disabled this but it stlil carried on.

**Further Update:**

I went to the MSI website and downloaded all of the drivers for my motherboard etc but this did not solve the problem.

Update:
Wired keyboard doesn't have the problem so working theory is some sort of bluetooth interferance or else the keyboard is broken.  I'm going to check the BIOS to turn off the bluetooth.

Further Update:
The keyboard works on a different computer so we can assume the keyboard is not the issue

Further, Further Update:
I had a new keyboard that worked fine until I needed to submit a proposal.  I assume they know about these things and do it deliberately.  I'm guessing we can rule out the keyboard.  It must be some sort of Blutooth interferance.

I wonder if the computer opposite mine is too close and causing problems.  I will move the desks and see if that helps.

[image: device manager bluetooth devices]

Comment: A key piece of information you should add to your question is whether or not you've tried another keyboard and if you experience the same issue with other keyboards.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the Surface line of computers was started in 2012, years before your keyboard, and it was already confusing because in 2007 Microsoft released a computer built into a multitouch table also called [Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PixelSense).

Comment: @Hashgrammer thank you, that's good advice.  The trouble I have is not having a spare keyboard, I'll find one and test it.
gronostaj that's even more annoying ha ha.

Comment: Yea if you get a chance and find another keyboard works, (and trying to test the iffy keyboard on someone elses computer to see if it's the same issue) I would start by looking into 1 of 2 things. A driver issue, or a broken keyboard.

Comment: It's a new computer.  The keyboard has been fine for years.

Comment: So the keyboard works on the other computer in the office, so I'm going to blame the computer.  I've tried updating the drivers with no joy.